# validation of url in php

Tags: php

i have phpmydatagrid where separate buttons are available for users to enter,delete and edit datas.there is a column for entering url and i want to validate it(Eg:I want all the users to enter the full url with the http or https request and it should not be just www.something.com) and i want to know where exactly to enter the syntax 
I have attached the coding for the phpmydatagrid.

phpMyDatagrid - Sample file

```
/* Include class file */
include ("phpmydatagrid.class.php");

/* Create object */
$objGrid = new datagrid;

/* Define the "FORM" will be named employee and Must be 
   created by the grid script */
$objGrid -> form('employee', true);

/* Connect with the database */
$objGrid -> conectadb("localhost", "root", "mysql", "probe_config");

/* Select the table to use */
$objGrid -> tabla ("measurementurl");

$objGrid -> buttons(addbtn,updbtn,delbtn,false);




$objGrid -> datarows(5);

$objGrid -> paginationmode('mixed');


/* Define fields to show */

  $objGrid -> FormatColumn("id", "ID", 30, 30, 0, "150", "left");
$objGrid -> FormatColumn("name", "NAME", 30, 30, 0, "50", "right");
$objGrid -> FormatColumn("url", "url", 90, 90, 0, "90", "left");
    $objGrid -> FormatColumn("comment", "COMMENT", 30, 30, 0, "150", "left");


$objGrid -> keyfield("id");



/* The setHeader function MUST be set between the <HEAD> and </HEAD> 
   to correctly set the CSS and JS parameters */
$objGrid -> setHeader();
```

?>

```
$objGrid -> ajax("silent");

/* draw the grid */
    $objGrid -> grid();


/* Disconnect from database */
$objGrid -> desconectar();
```

?>

[home](http://localhost:8080/admin%20screen.html)

Answer (score 0):

PHP code:

```
function isValidURL($url)
{
return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
```

Use of function :

PHP code:

```
if(!isValidURL($fldbanner_url))
{
$errMsg .= "* Please enter valid URL including http://<br>";
}
```

Comment: thanks .i would like to know where exactly to insert your coding in my phpmydatagrid coding

Answer (score 0):

If you have the filter extension installed use the [filter_var](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function:

```
if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
  //Valid URL
} else {
  //Invalid URL
}
```